# Is this rejection due to automated screening?

Tags: job-search, united-states, applications, rejection

I applied for a bilingual flight attendant position at a large US-based airliner, but my application got rejected. The generic rejection letter is as follows (some parts have been left out or altered for anonymity purposes):

"Thank you for your interest in a career with X Air Lines.

We received an overwhelming response to Flight Attendant- X Speaking position which makes us feel both humble and proud that so many talented individuals like you want to join our team. This volume of response makes for an extremely competitive selection process. Although your background is impressive, we regret to inform you that we have decided to pursue other candidates for this position at this time.

We value our job candidates and invite you to review other job openings. We hope you see another job that you are qualified for and that sparks your interest!

Thanks again for your interest in a career with X Air Lines!"

The application process consisted of attaching my resume and answering a questionnaire. I submitted my application on the evening of Friday, August 10th, but I got the above response just two days later on Sunday evening. **Since the company referred to is a large company and there are numerous applicants, could it be that I got screened in some automatic process? I am asking this question because I submitted my application and got rejected over the weekend.** I assume that HR does not work on the weekends. To me, it is strange that I at least hear some sort of response from large companies, but hardly hear back anything from small firms.

Comment: What will you do differently, if the rejection was automatic or a hiring manager going through applications on a weekend?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: That is a good question that I don't have an answer to currently. It is great that I am posed with a counter-question to my question!

Comment: Well, we might be able to help you with a different question.  We have no way of knowing if the hiring manager likes to work on weekends when it is quiet, nor how that affects anything - it unfortunately doesn't change that you were rejected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't have a crystal ball

Comment: No problem! This site seems to be severely limited in what types of questions are allowed to be asked.

Comment: @user91155 yeah, that's been an issue recently... but, hey, don't be so absolute. You were basically asking us to *guess* what this company meant. Although SE accepts subjective questions, this I fear is only really answerable by that company... that being said, you were automatically rejected *xor* manually by a large recruiting crew... so, what difference would it make knowing that fact? What will be the benefit of knowing that?... I think we can see that such thing lacks a *goal*, and surely will be of few help for present and future users.

Comment: @user91155 anyways, feel free to rethink and rephrase your question into an on-topic form. It doesn't have to be perfect (we can help you edit it), but it has to be at least on-topic for us to be able to do that.

Comment: I would "guess" that it is very probable that your deduction is correct and it was automated.  The question (in my opinion) is a valid and good one but can not be answered without speculation.

Comment: My location is Taiwan. Whenever there is airline hiring flight attendants, there are tens of thousands of applicants waiting in line for interviews. Usually, the airline is looking to hire a couple of dozens of flight attendants. Your question sounds like you don't know how hot is the flight attendant jobs. Airline workers are always 24/7, even HR. This is because they are transportation industry. Days and nights, airplanes take off and land and fly. You never know when you have business to take care of. I know an airline HR working on shifts. Know their industry before you apply.

Comment: FWIW, it always better to avoid using a web form to make first contact with a potential employer. The whole point of online applications is to strictly filter out as many candidates as possible without concern for false negatives. Instead try to get to know people who are in the industry and get referred by them. This will at least make you stand out from the ocean of other applicants.

Comment: Delta does this. They scan job boards and spam people with language skills to apply, then reject you as described by the OP and then spam you again.